# Upload Folder of Images to Firestore Storage and Put Download URLs in Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I have roughly 10,000 images that I want to upload to Firebase Storage (it adds up to around 800mb).

Using Javascript, I am looking for a way to:

1. Upload them to Firebase Storage
2. Grab their URL upon upload and create Cloud Firestore documents for each using their file names with a field called "downloadURL" or something like that that my website can then use for  tags.

So say one file is 4670.jpg. I want to upload the file, grab its persistent URL and then create a Cloud Firestore document called 4670 that has a text field with it's persistent URL. I know how to do this for a single file, but I'm dealing with thousands.

**Edit: A huge thanks for, Renaud Tarnec who gave me a working solution**

**HTML**

```
// File selector

<input type="file" multiple onchange="processSelectedFiles(this)">

// CDN for Firebase, Cloud Firestore, and Firebase Storage
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.11.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.0/firebase-storage.js"></script>

<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "********************",
    authDomain: "********************",
    databaseURL: "********************",
    projectId: "********************",
    storageBucket: "********************",
    messagingSenderId: "********************"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);


var db = firebase.firestore();

</script>

<script src="script.js"></script>
```

**Javascript**

```
function processSelectedFiles(fileInput) {
  var files = fileInput.files;

  var promises = []

  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

    var file = files[i] 

      promises.push(uploadAndSavePromise(file))
  }

    Promise.all(promises);
}

function uploadAndSavePromise(file) {
     var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
     var fileName = file.name
     // Remove extension
     var trimmedFileName = fileName.slice(0, -4)

     var imageRef = storageRef.child('test/'+fileName);

    return imageRef.put(file).then(function(snapshot) {

        db.collection("maincollection").doc(trimmedFileName).set({
        imageURL: snapshot.downloadURL,

})

});

}
```

Comment: If you can do this for 1 file why cant you do it for 10, or 100, or 10000???

Comment: I assume this will involve writing a script that loops through a directory and performs the upload/save url to document for each image in the directory.

Comment: @rayfarer Yes indeed, but since the uploading and the save are asynchronous operations you have to deal with promises (or callbacks functions). See below how to do it with Promise.all.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! If you would like to thank @RenaudTarnec, select his answer below as the answer. Once you have enough reputation, upvote it answers that are helpful (in addition to selecting them as the answer). https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say that you know how to do for one single file.

You probably have a process based on promises which does something like (in pseudo code):

```
({Upload_to_Firebase_Storage_Promise})
.then(function(urlOfFile) {
    {create__Firestore_doc_Promise}
})
.catch(....)
```

What you should do is to use Promise.all() following this pattern (a mix of JavaScript and pseudo code):

```
var promises = [];

{forEach file to upload} (
  //Create a Promise that upload the file and save the url and add this promise to the array, as follow
  promises.push(uploadAndSavePromise(fileToUpload))
)

//and call    
Promise.all(promises);
```

where uploadAndSavePromise is a function implementing the initial promise chain:

```
function uploadAndSavePromise(file) {
    return ({Upload_to_Firebase_Storage_Promise(file)})
    .then(function(urlOfFile) {
        {create__Firestore_doc_Promise}
    });
}
```

Now, one thing that I would consider is how is this is going to work if you want to upload 10000 images in a row...

Comment: Thank you, I will study this. And while there are total of 10,000 images, I will probably do them in batches of 200-500.

Comment: Renaud, thank you so much. I have posted a working solution at the top (hopefully the question is removed from hold, I couldn't find a similar answer, so hopefully this helps other people who are new to Firebase Storage!)

Comment: @rayfarer You may accept the answer by clicking the grey checkmark on the left side. Thanks!